# I need help for connect js functions with ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
I wonder how I can insert JS functions into an EJS file?
```

I have this function:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYThQ.png)

I tried to create a separate .ejs file where I will insert a function between the tags <% %> and also import it into the ЕЈS file that I need, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about not posting pictures of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS does not provide a DOM. Output from EJS is generated using `<%=` and similar.

The `document` object is only (that's a slight simplification) available in JS running in an HTML document in the browser.

To use that code you would need to include it in a `<script>` element output from the EJS into an HTML document and run in a browser.